# Maximo Data Dictionary

Tags: maximo

Is there any chance to split all maximo tables into master data and transnational tables?
For SAP and JDE exists a lot of data dictionary to determine both groups.
Do we have something similar for maximo?

I have found nothing so far.

Comment: Did you really mean to say "transnational tables" -- tables that cross nations? Or did you mean "translational tables" for converting between languages? Or did you mean "transactional tables", like the MATRECTRANS for recording material receipt transactions? Either way, I suggest querying the MAXOBJECT table. If I may say so, Maximo's table names make sense, unlike JDE or SAP, so you could even just browse the schema and probably make good guesses.

Comment: MAXOBJECT is like the Fwhatever table in JDE and SAP that tells you what all the other objects are for. You will want to filter for `persistent = 1`  if you only want to get back names of objects with tables you can query. You could use your SQL tool's object name filter to find all the %TRANS tables, but MAXOBJECT will give you a full English description. MAXATTRIBUTE is similar, but for attributes / columns.

Comment: @Preacher: Thanks a lot. Indeed, I mean transactional data like MATRECTRANS.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to distinguish transactional data. It is down to you to define which is which. It really depends on how the system is being used, e.g. for some customers changes to locations status (LOCSTATUS) could be transactional and in others not.